# Will the next release of Delphi be supporting cross-compilation for Mac and Linux?

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, cross-compiling

According to a [recent blog post](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2010/01/26/38908) by Allen Bauer:

> As we’re working on Fulcrum, the next
>   RAD Studio release with a focus on
>   cross-compilation for Mac and Linux,
>   [..]

I figured someone would mention it in the comments, but I thought Mac/Linux support was a few releases further off. Maybe it's just me, but this is *huge* news.

Does this mean we will see Mac/Linux binaries created with a Delphi release this year?

Comment: This is indeed a big news. Would be really nice to be able to release current products to Mac too. I just hope this won't be a feature that will be released "too soon" (with a "beta" quality).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I cannot commit to any kind of time frame or release dates, we are working on Mac and Linux targeting. There is also some work going on for 64bit targeting as well, however that will most likely **not** be in the same time frame as the Mac/Linux targeted releases.

Comment: What about Google Native Client, do you have any plans for that?

Comment: If it ever becomes significantly more popular, I'm sure we'd look into it.

Comment: I hope at least a beta version of 64-bit compiler - maybe not fully supporting VCL - is released with the next Delphi release (Fulcrum); so that people who really need it, specially for developing 64-bit shell extensions or DLLs can use it until the fully functional 64-bit compiler is released.

Comment: Therein lies the rub. What you consider a "beta" or "preview" others would consider it a useless and "pre-alpha." Even from your statement about what you want to do with it indicates that it would need to be nearly complete (and bug free). What if it was delivered with a bug that made it impossible to build your shell extension? I'd imagine you'd change your tune since it simply didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Does it mean that the same VCL based application will recompile for Linux and Mac without seignificant changes?

Comment: So Linux is still expected to release together with the Mac bit?

Comment: Andrei,
  No. The GUI bits of VCL are inextricably tied to the Windows API. We're working on a GUI framework that retains the feel of VCL, but is truly cross platform. A large portion of the non-GUI bits from the RTL and DB portions will recompile across, with all the normal caveats. More details will come as we get further along in the release cycle.

Comment: Marco,
  Some Linux support is planned. I cannot comment on how complete and to what level right now... mainly because it all depends on how the Mac work shakes down.

Comment: Would there at least be some new types / constants to prepare for 64 bitness in the next version? In the line of IntPtr = Integer / Int64; PointerSize = 4/8 etc etc?

In Delphi 2007 I did miss the fact that there is no UnicodeString (alias of Widestring) so you are left to using $if's .

Comment: We will begin talking about how you can prepare for 64bit at some point.

Comment: So, a "Cross-platform Library for project X" ...? or CLX for short.  It's deja vu all over again.  I guess some people just don't learn from their own (huge) mistakes.  And you;ll have to pardon some cynicism... based on recent history there is every reason to suspect that by the time Delphi 2011 comes around Project X will have been put onto a back burner and some other new and previously unmentioned project being given priority.  Sadly, even sincere reassurances that this won't happen will smell a bit funny given that this is exactly what happened with Commodore, roadmap or no roadmap.

Comment: @Allen - I guess 64-bit version may not support VCL at all, right or not?

Comment: @Serg, 64bit *Windows* will have the VCL.

Comment: @Deltics,

  Maybe you're right, and then again, maybe not. I guess we'll all have to wait and see.

Answer (score 5):

Fulcrum is the code name for the next release, so yes, the next release will include Mac and Linux support.  I don't know about the time frame, but "this year" seems reasonable.

Native 64 bit support will be in a future release.

Personally, I prefer this order.

Comment: Anyone heard of a possible release time frame for 'Fulcrum'?

Comment: Keep an eye out for the next CodeRage.  If the pattern holds, the release will be around the same time.

Comment: For me it's a big Big BIG disappointment if there will be no x64 support in the next Delphi release. I think Embarcadero/Delphi will loose lots of developers because of this (and not gain a fraction of them by supporting cross compilation).

Comment: @Remko - Do you think Fulcrum will also be 64-bit? The reason I think it might is because OSX is 100% 64-bit. Maybe that's gonna be a big surprise for us all that they deliver both at once....ok, I'm probably just dreaming

Comment: Usually Delphi does q2/q3 releases, My guess is they'll stick with that to keep all the subscribers happy.

Comment: @Remko: AFAIK, Fulcrum will not have native 64 bit.  There was a big thread in Embarcadero's non-tech forum recently about this, and only a small handful of people could even explain why they need it NOW.  I don;t think putting cross platform first will cost many customers.  Like I said, I'm really happy about the current priorities.

Comment: @Mick: Like 64 bit Windows, OSX runs 32 bit applications just fine.  I don;t know if there are any exceptions or not.

Comment: @Mick/Zartog: I hope to see these questions answered in the Fulcrum briefing for Technology Partners which is coming up.

Answer (score 5):

Embarcadero once said that "the release after the next one will support 64-bit".  That was supposed to be Delphi 2010.  That didn't happen of course - far from it.  Not only did it not appear in the release that was indicated, but it now appears it won't be appearing for at least 2 further releases, and in the meantime, things that were NEVER even mentioned have suddenly appeared and been given priority.

So there really is no reason to believe that Fulcrum will happen either, until it has actually been delivered, no matter who talks about it, at least not in the time frame that is being indicated.

Embarcadero have proven less than reliable when it comes to their "roadmap" which is frankly something of a joke - the "current" one still talks about things that have already been delivered as if they have yet to happen, for instance.

Comment: "Welcome to the real world, Neo." ;-)

Comment: Yeah, this drives me insane. How can anyone reliably plan around what they're going to release next? They're just making it up as they go.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the last [road map](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934), you will see Embarcadero is working on Project called "Delphi X"

[image]
<sub>(source: [embarcadero.com](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/39934/0300000B.png))</sub>

and according to what Allen said, it seems it's will be compile to Mac OS & Linux at same time, which is great thing.

Answer (score 2):

[FreePascal](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/)

I suppose it's not *awful* news...

Answer (score 1):

If Allen said so, it's pretty safe to assume it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer so far is by Michael Rozlog. It is an over hour interview with the Product Manager of RAD Studio and is worth hearing. It covers:

- The Delphi Survey
- Delphi application showcase
- Updates to the Delphi Roadmap
- 12 Videos of Christmas (later renamed the 12 Holiday videos)
- Compiler rewrite
- Project Fulcrum: Delphi on Linux and Mac in Beta
- Coming soon to more public beta (hopefully)
- Delphi Backwards Compatibility
- The upgrade cut off policy
- Free or low cost versions of Delphi
- And a whole lot more.

http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/f/65775?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+delphifeeds+(DelphiFeeds.com)